# azure databricks notebook rebase

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-repos

I am trying to rebase my feature branch to the latest commit of the master branch.
In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/github-version-control#rebase-a-branch) I saw there is a button for rebase, but in my notebook I only see the create branch button. Any idea how to do rebase in azure databricks notebook?[image]

Comment: is your feature branch is forked directly from the master branch?

Comment: @AlexOtt yes, it is.

Comment: added answer. TLDR - error in docs

Answer (score 0):

Rebase button appears only when you are working on Feature branch and some new updates are pushed on master branch(default branch)

Make sure you follow both conditions as given in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/github-version-control#rebase-a-branch)

1. The Rebase link displays if new commits are available in the parent branch.
2. Only rebasing on top of the default branch of the parent repository is supported.

Comment: There is no rebase button showing up. My feature branch is 65 commits behind the origin/master. I met the conditions.

Comment: That’s incorrect, it was a error in docs

Answer (score 0):

That's really a problem with the docs caused by some internal processes. Repos doesn't support rebase functionality - it is only supported for files in Workspaces.